# Types of List separator in sass

Tags: css, sass

I know three types of separators in SASS, comma, space and auto, but what is the difference between comma and auto because I can see If I use nothing with LIST as separator It takes comma, for comma it accepts comma and for auto it accepts auto.

```
$listUnquote:One, Two Three, Four;
$listSpaceSapareted:"One" "Two" "Three" "Four";    
jointAuto{join:join($listUnquote, $listSpaceSapareted, auto)}
jointComma{join:join($listUnquote, $listSpaceSapareted, comma)}
jointblank{join:join($listUnquote, $listSpaceSapareted)}
```

The above code spits out the same values.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the `auto` behaviour:

> Unless `$separator` is passed, if one list is comma-separated and one is space-separated, the first parameter’s separator is used for the resulting list. If both lists have fewer than two items, spaces are used for the resulting list.

Just altering the order of the lists, change the output:

```
$commaList: One, Two, Three, Four;
$spaceList: "One" "Two" "Three" "Four"; 

@warn(join($commaList, $spaceList, auto));
@warn(join($spaceList, $commaList, auto));
```

[Pen](http://codepen.io/elrumordelaluz/pen/514f2541ba03b1cd033243db3c0ce985?editors=0101)